# Contour plot with python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

This is my code. I tried using it to plot the contour, however, I get two plots on the same grid. exactly half instead of a full plot. I mean my grid is 20 units in x direction however, my resulting plot is 10 units in x direction with replica plot from 10 to 20 units. Can you please look whats wrong?
v is a numpy array of 20x10

```
x, y = range(0, 20), range(0,10)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(x, y)


# Interpolate
rbf = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(xi, yi, v)
zi = rbf(xi, yi)

plt.imshow(zi, vmin = 1.6, vmax=2)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your current code doesn't make much sense. You're "interpolating" at the exact locations of your data points.  (I.e. `zi` is going to be identical to `v`.) It sounds like `v` is already on a regular grid? If so, skip the interpolation and contour it directly.

Comment: @JoeKington Thank you it worked. You are an inspiration to me. :)